# Can i add my own label in offline map

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, mapbox

[image]I am developing a app in android using MapBox SDK (https://www.mapbox.com/blog/android-sdk/) for offline map.
I am using mbtiles file for offline map.
Is there any way or method to add my own custom label to that offline map?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change labels that are part of the tile images you will have to create your own map tiles. You can create these tiles with [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/).

Perhaps you could get away with using [markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-android-sdk/#overlays) instead?